# Collateral Management - Initial Margin Frequency

Tags: collateral, initial-margin

My understanding is that initial margin presents over collateralization and comes into play in an actual default scenario as it aims to cover closeout costs.
I was wondering what is the frequency of Initial Margins ? (i.e: I know the new norm with variation margins' frequency is daily)

Thanks

Comment: IM formalities are covered in, for example, an ISDA IM credit support annex if you have an ISDA arrangement in place. It covers thresholds, minimum transfer amounts (MTA) and payment frequencies. Of course, this agreement must be in accordance with current law. For example, the EU stipulates a calculation no less than every 10 days, see for example Article 9 (2)e for the European Union  (https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R2251&from=GA. In practice, the calculation frequency is commonly daily and exchange takes place when the amount exceeds the MTA.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Very clear